# arcgis server 10, vb.net, non pooled service, web adf

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcgis-server, vb.net

i am running arcgis server 10. i created a A.MXD file, then started arcgis server and successfully added non-pooled service using A.MXD. i also installed visual web developer 2010 express and created new web mapping application using vb.net, and pointed mapresourcemanager to the one running my A.MXD. now, i want to be able to generate custom layers when user clicks on a button and add them to the service, i.e. it would display it as part of A.MXD on the website but not on the actual file on the server machine (for this reason i made it non-pooled service). plz can anyone help me with suggestions, samples, short tutorials that probably i have missed searching...? or at least a python script. thanks!